# Are the Super Saiyan Berseker and the Legendary Super Saiyan transformation the same thing?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Kale's first transformation (the bulky one with blank eyes) was officially called super saiyan berseker. Now from Broly's movie, we knew a similar transformation was called the legendary super saiyan transformation.

That was a non canon name, but in the last Dragon Ball Super episode preview they made a reference to that name.

We also know Kale has at least 2 transformations, her berserker transformation, and her calm transformation (also known unofficially as super Saiyan green) and last episode preview hinted Kale could have more transformations (another calm transformation where she controls her full power, something she supposedly didn't do with super Saiyan green apparently ?  maybe a super saiyan 3 for her coming) .

So my question is, are the super Saiyan berseker and the legendary super Saiyan transformation the same transformation, or are they refers with legendary super Saiyan transformation to another transformation from Kale (not the first one we've seen from her)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was mentioned in episode 114 that the Berserker state was basically an uncontrolled version of the LSSJ. We see Kale being able to control this enormous power and go toe to toe with SSJG Goku. So the answer to your question would be a yes!